# date-fns | How do I format to UTC

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, date-fns

### Problem

It looks like when I use the `format()` function, it automatically convert the original UTC time into my timezone (UTC+8). I have been digging through their docs for hours and couldn't seem to find a way to default it to UTC time.

```js
import { parseISO, format } from "date-fns";

const time = "2019-10-25T08:10:00Z";

const parsedTime = parseISO(time);
console.log(parsedTime); // 2019-10-25T08:10:00.000Z

const formattedTime = format(parsedTime, "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
console.log(formattedTime); // 2019-10-25 16:10:00 <-- 8 HOURS OFF!!
```

I have tried to use the package `data-fns-tz` and use something like

```js
format(parsedTime, "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss", {timeZone: "UTC"});
```

still no luck.

Please help!

### Expected Output

`2019-10-25 08:10:00`

### Actual Output

`2019-10-25 16:10:00`

Comment: I have tested your code here. This seems to work fine. https://repl.it/repls/RepentantDimFactor

Comment: @khan - repl.it runs in UTC, that's why.

Comment: When parsed, 2019-10-25 08:10:00 will be interpreted as local, not UTC, and will be treated as an invalid date in some browsers.

Comment: UPDATE: they have a new package https://github.com/date-fns/utc with `UTCDate` class which might be simpler/safer?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would suggest using the built-in `Date` util:

```
const date = new Date("2019-10-25T08:10:00Z");
const isoDate = date.toISOString();

console.log(`${isoDate.substring(0, 10)} ${isoDate.substring(11, 19)}`);
```

Outputs:

`2019-10-25 08:10:00`

Not a general solution for any format, but no external libraries required.

Comment: Thank for the reply, but sadly, the reason I chose to use a library is that I need to do calculation on dates :(

Comment: You can still use `date-fns` for everything except that last part for output.  It does return, afterall, `Date` objects.

Comment: Looks like this is the only way out if I want to use date-fns. Excellent answer!

Comment: I like this solution. It's correct and a one-liner.

Answer (score 64):

You were almost there.  This works for me:

```
import { parseISO } from "date-fns";
import { format, utcToZonedTime } from "date-fns-tz";

const time = "2019-10-25T08:10:00Z";

const parsedTime = parseISO(time);
console.log(parsedTime); // 2019-10-25T08:10:00.000Z

const formatInTimeZone = (date, fmt, tz) =>
  format(utcToZonedTime(date, tz), 
         fmt, 
         { timeZone: tz });

const formattedTime = formatInTimeZone(parsedTime, "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss xxx", "UTC");
console.log(formattedTime); // 2019-10-25 08:10:00 +00:00
```

#### Behind the scenes

The date-fns[-tz] libraries stick to the built-in `Date` data type that [carries no TZ info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/239657).
Some functions treat it as a moment-in-time, but some like `format` treat it more like a struct of calendaric components — year 2019, ..., day 25, hour 08, ....

Now the trouble is a `Date` is internally only a moment in time.  Its methods provide a mapping to/from calendaric components in *local time zone*.

So to represent a different time zone, `date-fns-tz/utcToZonedTime` temporarily produces `Date` instances which represent the **wrong moment in time** — just to get its calendaric components in local time to be what we want!

And the `date-fns-tz/format` function's timeZone input affects *only* the template chars that print the time zone (`XX..X`, `xx..x`, `zz..z`, `OO..O`).

See https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz/issues/36 for some discussion of this "shifting" technique (and of real use cases that motivated them)...
It's a bit low-level & risky, but the specific way I composed them above — `formatInTimeZone()` — is I believe a safe recipe.

Comment: For anyone wondering if this is a hack or not -- It's in fact the official way of formatting to a certain timezone, including UTC: https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz#format

Comment: But the jury is still out on whether the official way is a hack or not :-D  Specifically I'm worried about calendaric times that do not exist in _some_ time zones e.g. https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-16351377 — if your local TZ is Samoa, no timestamp maps to 30 December 2011, so if you want to format that date from another TZ I'm not sure it'd work.

Comment: This works for me. Took me a few tries before I realized that the `format` import must come from `date-fns-tz` and not the core `date-fns`, but worked after that.

Comment: @nerrons it being official does not make it "not a hack". It is certainly still a hack, and an ugly one, too. Shame that in JS one must go to such lengths to perform something this trivial.

Answer (score 33):

**Note**
*The following solution will not work for all time zones, so if timezone accuracy is critical for your application you might want to try something like the answer from Beni. See this [link](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/1401#issuecomment-621897094) for more info*

I had the exact same question today and did some research to see if anyone has come up with anything better since this question was posed. I came across [this](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/1401#issuecomment-578580199) solution which fit my needs and stylistic preference:

```
import { format, addMinutes } from 'date-fns';

function formatDate(date) {
  return format(addMinutes(date, date.getTimezoneOffset()), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
}
```

#### Explanation

`getTimezoneOffset` returns the number of minutes needed to convert that date to UTC. In PST (-0800 hours) it would return 480 whereas for somebody on CST (+0800 hours) it would return -480.

Comment: You should note that this solution does not work for all timezones, as pointed out in the thread you referred to: https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/1401#issuecomment-621897094

Comment: @Sherwin, for me instead of doing +5.30 , it is doing -5.30 .  So how should I correct it.?

Comment: @KomalKhatkole getTimezoneOffset returns the number of minutes needed to convert your local time to a UTC time, so if your offset is +5:30 it will return -330 minutes. Is this what's happening?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. What I do is remove the timezone from the ISO string and then use that time with date-fns:

`let time = "2019-10-25T08:10:00Z".slice(0, -1)`

The above is a time with no time zone, and because there is no timezone date-fns assumes the local timezone, so when you do:

`format(parseISO(time), 'h:mm a')`

you get: **8:10 AM**, or whatever format you prefer. You just have to be careful with the string that you are slicing. If its always the same format then it should work.

Answer (score 10):

I did something like this using date/fns and native date methods

```js
import format from 'date-fns/format';
import parseISO from 'date-fns/parseISO';

export const adjustForUTCOffset = date => {
  return new Date(
    date.getUTCFullYear(),
    date.getUTCMonth(),
    date.getUTCDate(),
    date.getUTCHours(),
    date.getUTCMinutes(),
    date.getUTCSeconds(),
  );
};

const formatDate = (dateString) = > {
    const date = parseISO(dateString);
    const dateWithOffset = adjustForUTCOffset(date)
    return format(dateWithOffset, 'LLL dd, yyyy HH:mm')
}
```

Comment: I am stuck on 1.30.1 for now and this worked for me

Comment: I don't if there are more solutions but definitely this is the easiest

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I did it

```js
const now = new Date()
  const date = format(
    new Date(now.toISOString().slice(0, -1)),
    'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
  )
```

I just removed the Z from the ISO string. I'm not sure if it solves this [issue](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/1401#issuecomment-621897094) though

Answer (score 1):

solution for timestamp

```
format(utcToZonedTime(timestamp, 'UTC'), 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a', { timeZone: 'UTC' })
```

Answer (score 0):

This works using only the date-fns provided functionality.

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import { utcToZonedTime } from 'date-fns-tz';

const date = new Date(); // This could be any date

// Convert the local date to UTC
const utcDate = utcToZonedTime(date, 'Etc/UTC');

// Format the UTC date
const formattedDate = format(utcDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

console.log(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about UTC, you can use [@date-fns/utc](https://github.com/date-fns/utc):

```
import { UTCDateMini } from "@date-fns/utc";
import { format } from 'date-fns';

const given = "2019-10-25T08:10:00Z";
const format = "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss";

const utcDate = new UTCDateMini(given);
const formatted = format(utcDate, format); // 2019-10-25 08:10:00
```

Answer (score -3):

try

```js
const formatDate = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

Answer (score -3):

I guess

To construct the date as UTC before parsing would be helpful.

```
import { parseISO, format } from "date-fns";

const time = "2019-10-25T08:10:00Z";

const parsedTime = parseISO(new Date(Date.UTC(time)));
const formattedTime = format(parsedTime, "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
```

like this.

Comment: The `parsedTime` from your snippet returns InvalidDate

Comment: The answer is partially correct, but he missed the usage of parseISO. I edited the answer

`
const parsedTime = parseISO(new Date(Date.UTC(time)));
`