# date fns format output as utc +0

Tags: date-fns

Hoe can I get the format as UTC +0?

```
const txDate = fromUnixTime(1573094560) 
console.log(txDate)
console.log(format(txDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z'))
```

Output:

```
2019-11-07T02:42:40.000Z
2019-11-07 10:42:40 GMT+8
```

Comment: Hope the below link can help you to get some ideas. https://www.codementor.io/ayushgupta/date-and-time-in-javascript-fg1zamk72

Comment: ^^ This link is broken

Comment: You can try my answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61469549/800198