# date-fns how to remove date from a Unix formatted timestamp?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have been given a Unix formatted timestamp in milliseconds, but I would like to remove the date so I only have the hours/minutes/seconds instead of the date so I can compare the time value to another time value that might have a different date. Is there a way to do this using date-fns?

I know I can get the timestamp as a date with `fromUnixTime(timeStamp)` but I can't figure out how to extract the date only to return just the timestamp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Comment: or [How do I get the current time only in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599148/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-only-in-javascript) or [JS: parse time to pull out hours and minutes using date-fns, ignroing timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345759/js-parse-time-to-pull-out-hours-and-minutes-using-date-fns-ignroing-timezones)

Comment: sorry but none of those deal with a unix timestamp and return another unix timestamp minus anything but hours, minutes, seconds etc. (no date) from epoch.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need extra libraries to do this, the built-in `Date` object is pretty versatile (and if you really do, date-fns uses the `Date` object under the hood). Given a date object, all you need to do is use [`.getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours), [`.getMinutes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes), and [`.getSeconds()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getSeconds) functions. If you have your data in some format other than a JavaScript date object, then just convert it into a `Date` object (for the more obvious formats, just passing it to `new Date()` will do). Like this:

```js
const fromUnixTime = (date) => `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`;

console.log(fromUnixTime(new Date())); // current time
console.log(fromUnixTime(new Date(1205400000000))); // from some miliseconds since the epoch
console.log(fromUnixTime(new Date('Thu Mar 13 2008 04:20:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)'))); // from a full datetime string
```

Comment: 14 year old duplicate with over 2000 upvotes

Comment: this is not a timestamp. This is a string. Thanks for the answer though. 

I do realise what I am doing is very niche and I actually ended up asking the wrong question anyway. What I really need to do is find the difference between the input date (a string) and the output (a timestamp that might possibly be more than 24 hours in the future)

Comment: But to add on I think the answer to the question I asked would be to take your answer but change it so that  the function returns ```(date.getHours()*60*60*1000)+(date.getMinutes()*60*1000)+(date.getSeconds()*1000)```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use what Michael posted, but to return a valid JS Unix timestamp in milliseconds, all using functions from `date-fns`:

```
const removeDateFromUnixTime(timeStamp) => {
    const date = fromUnixTime(timeStamp);
    const hoursInMillis = hoursToMilliseconds(getHours(date));
    const minutesInMillis = minutesToMilliseconds(getMinutes(date));
    const secondsInMillis = secondsToMilliseconds(getSeconds(date));
    return hoursInMillis +  minutesInMillis + secondsInMillis;
}
```