# Going from moment.js to date-fns: UTC formatting issues

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-fns

I'm trying to go from moment.js to date-fns, but I'm having issues formatting the dates correctly..

My date looks like this: `const convertDate = '2006-03-07T23:00:00.000Z'`
I'm trying to convert it to: 2006-03-07

In moment.js I did it like this:
`moment.utc(convertDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')` --> 2006-03-07

In date-fns I tried to do it like this: `format(new Date(convertDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd')` --> 2006-03-08

I have figured that I somehow need to convert my date to UTC before doing the formatting with date-fns, but it don't seems like this is possible? Any input on this?

Comment: `'2006-03-07T23:00:00.000Z'.substring(0,10)` does the job for me. Or `'2006-03-07T23:00:00.000Z'.split('T')[0]`. Or `'2006-03-07T23:00:00.000Z'.slice(0,10)`. :-)

Comment: While just using the substring is a pragmatic approach and will certainly will work for your usecase, check this question [date-fns | How do I format to UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561169/date-fns-how-do-i-format-to-utc)  Especially look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63227335/3776927) which will allow you to use also different formats (ie not only YYYY-MM-DD from the ISO String)