# Issue with Parsing Date and Time Using Date-FNS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, date-fns

I have here a date and time and I'm wondering its outputting an incorrect date and time.
`2022-05-19T21:53:00+00:00`. Its currently outputting May 20. It should be May 19 still?

CODESANDBOX: [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-fns-v2-forked-hoge23?file=/src/index.js:0-180)

```
import { format, parseISO } from "date-fns";

let date = "2022-05-19T21:53:00+00:00";

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div>${format(parseISO(date), "LLL dd, y hh:mm bbb")}</div>
`;
```

Comment: It depends on your timezone. If you want it output as UTC you need to specify, otherwise it will be displayed in the system's timezone. (Displays `May 19, 2022 10:53 pm` for me in UTC+1) see: [date-fns | How do I format to UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561169/date-fns-how-do-i-format-to-utc)

Comment: @pilchard. Thanks. I wanted output it as whats on the given. I'm confused on what to follow on the link you provided. Can you put your answer below? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need `date-fns` you can simply use a native [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) with [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

```js
let date = "2022-05-19T21:53:00+00:00";

const options = {
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  year: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  timeZone: 'UTC'
};

const dateLocaleString = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('en', options);

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div>${dateLocaleString}</div>
`;
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. what do you call this format? `2022-05-19T21:53:00+00:00`?

Comment: That's an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string.